# In mongoDB, automatically update field after 2 weeks

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We have the following document in our mongodb collection for users.

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('2u3ijfasdjfkajw3ljkajdkajsf')
  firstName: 'Mike',
  lastName: 'Jones',
  tier: { value: 1, label: 'free' },
  trialTimeEnds: ''
}
```

I'd like to offer users a two week trial to our website, which means updating their `tier` from `tier: { value: 1, label: 'free' }` to `tier: { value: 2, label: 'trial' }`. After 2 weeks, I'd like for the tier to automatically revert back to `{ value: 1, label: 'free' }`. Is it possible to set an `expires` or `trialTimeEnds` timestamp that, once the time is reaching, triggers the `tier` to convert back to `value: 1`?

If not possible in Mongo, is there then a simple way to do this in Node JS?

Answer (score 0):

It would be recommended to create another collection for the tier.

**db**

```
db={
  "user": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("61e52e26fd6b5909358c902a"),
      "firstName": "Mike",
      "lastName": "Jones"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("61e52e26fd6b5909358c902b"),
      "firstName": "Lebron",
      "lastName": "James"
    }
  ],
  "tier": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "tier": "free",
      "lastDays": 9999,
      "price": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "tier": "trial",
      "lastDays": 14,
      "price": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "tier": "vip",
      "lastDays": 365,
      "price": 100
    }
  ],
  "tierRecord": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "user_id": ObjectId("61e52e26fd6b5909358c902a"),
      "tier_id": 2,
      "activeDate": ISODate("2022-01-01T11:23:25.184Z")
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "user_id": ObjectId("61e52e26fd6b5909358c902a"),
      "tier_id": 3,
      "activeDate": ISODate("2022-01-15T12:10:22.153Z")
    }
  ]
}
```

**aggregate**

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": ObjectId("61e52e26fd6b5909358c902a")
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "tierRecord",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "user_id",
      "as": "docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$docs"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "tier",
      "localField": "docs.tier_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "tiers"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      firstName: 1,
      lastName: 1,
      activeDate: "$docs.activeDate",
      lastDays: {
        $first: "$tiers.lastDays"
      },
      tier: {
        $first: "$tiers.tier"
      },
      endDate: {
        $dateAdd: {
          startDate: "$docs.activeDate",
          unit: "day",
          amount: {
            $first: "$tiers.lastDays"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      endDate: -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-r7VPro9-jW)